# How to remove spaces generated by span tag?

Tags: html, removing-whitespace

I have inserted single letters in span tag. While running this web page on the browser, span tag insert 4 pixel space automatically before every letter. I want to remove that space. Please suggest me best solution.

```html
<span>h</span>
<span>e</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>o</span>
<span></span>
<span>w</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>r</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>d</span>
```

Comment: do you need to achieve it using only html or css??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just Don’t Break the Line Make It In Continuous Form In Order To Achieve Your Solution

```html
<span>h</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span><span></span><span>w</span><span>o</span><span>r</span><span>l</span><span>d</span>
```

Comment: This is the only correct way in my opinion.

Comment: @Swapnil Kotkar let me know if you find my solution helpful

Answer (score 1):

By using [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) css properties, you can remove white space and align adjacently.

```css
span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<span>h</span>
<span>e</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>o</span>
<span></span>
<span>w</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>r</span>
<span>l</span>
<span>d</span>
```

> `table-cell` : These elements behave like `<td>` HTML elements

Comment: If he does not put them on new lines, there will be no spaces. using `table-cell` might show the correct output but is not the right way of doing this. the container of a element using `table-cell` should have `display:table` and would result in more whitespace. (but thats my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

As noted this is occurring because of the white space between adjacent lines - you can remove by wrapping the spans in a div with display: flex on it. and by giving the empty span a width of 1ch

the ch - represents the width, or more precisely the advance measure, of the glyph "0" (zero, the Unicode character U+0030) in the element's font).

Although I would do this differently entirely and **you do NOT need to use jQuery for such a simple thing**.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex
}

span:empty {
  width: 1ch
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>h</span>
  <span>e</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>w</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>r</span>
  <span>l</span>
  <span>d</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Jquery to remove the spaces between span tag.

```js
        //jquery
        $('p').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; }).remove();
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <p>
        <span>h</span>
        <span>e</span>
        <span>l</span>
        <span>l</span>
        <span>o</span>
        <span>w</span>
        <span>o</span>
        <span>r</span>
        <span>l</span>
        <span>d</span>
        </p>
```

Comment: why to make simpler thing more complex??

Comment: I don't understand this answer is accepted. It's a dirty fix. Just don't put them on new lines. This will show the spaces till the jQuery runs. It will also run on all `p` elements...

Comment: And what if editor auto format the code @GertB.

Comment: @Gert B. That’s what i am thinking of !!

Comment: @HritikPotawade That would be a mistake in the editor, no? spans are inline elements. And Still, your code effects all `p` elements on the page

Comment: Yes.You are right Hritik Potawade. This is the best solution when editor auto format our tags on different lines.

Comment: @Swapnil Kotkar  why to make simpler thing more complex??

Comment: @GertB. In above solution I've manipulated <p> tag but you can use class or id.

Comment: @HritikPotawade there is no reason why jQuery is the right solution. Worst case, when the output cannot be changed, a css solution would be better. Fixing style and position issues with jQuery is not ok. As I commented before. the spaces will be there till the js runs and will then be removed. Apart from that, who says the jQuery library is already included in the project?

Comment: @Gert B I think this answer need to be closed/removed although might be other will have an confusion too regarding to correct solution